# Loop through 3 photos and save each one with incremented name

Tags: save-as

I can get it to properly upload all 1, 2 or 3 files with the code entered as this--

```
else{
    string Path = Server.MapPath("~/IncomingPhotos/" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(Path);
    }
```

But I need to be able to save each file with a name like this--

1.1003.IncomingPhoto1

1.1003.IncomingPhoto2

1.1003.IncomingPhoto3

1 indicates the order_id, 1003 indicates the customer_id.

Form Code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" class="auto-style2" colspan="2">
             <asp:FileUpload ID="PackagingPhoto1" runat="server" Width="437px" AllowMultiple="True" />
          </td>
        </tr>                    
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center">
             <asp:Button ID="packagingPhotos" runat="server" OnClick="packagingPhotos_Click" Text="Upload 
             Photos" Width="175px" />
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void packagingPhotos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {           
                if (PackagingPhoto1.HasFile && PackagingPhoto1.PostedFiles.Count <= 3)
                {
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile file in PackagingPhoto1.PostedFiles) 
                    {                    
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        if (extension.ToLower() != ".jpeg" && extension.ToLower() != ".jpg" && extension.ToLower() != ".png")
                        {
                            Label9.Text = "Only files with .jpg, .jpeg, or .png extension are allowed.";
                            Label9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int photoSize = file.ContentLength;
                            if (photoSize > 5242880)
                            {
                                Label9.Text = "Maximum file size (5MB) exceeded!";
                                Label9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) 
                                { 
                                    string Path = Server.MapPath("~/IncomingPhotos/" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "." + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + ".ReceivingPhoto" + i + extension);
                                    file.SaveAs(Path);
                                }
                                Label9.Text = "Photos were successfully uploaded.";
                                Label9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }            
                }
                else
                {
                    Label9.Text = "Please select at least 1 but no more than 3 files.";
                    Label9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
```

Comment: After further troubleshooting, I've determined that the issue is something to do with the way I am naming the file when saving. If I change the following it works, but I need to save each file with a custom name.

`string Path = Server.MapPath("~/IncomingPhotos/" + file.FileName);
                                file.SaveAs(Path);
                            }`

Comment: why are you saving each file three times?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know why.. clearly I am missing the understanding on part of my code. If you could explain how I can save 3 different photos 1 time, rather than 1 of 3 photos 3 times, that would probably solve my problem.

Comment: I've edited my question a bunch this morning as I've been troubleshooting.. maybe a re-read is necessary?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are instantianting your counter variable (i) in the wrong spot and you have an unnecessary for loop.

Step 1:
declare and instantiate your counter variable to 0 on the line above your foreach loop.  While you're at it, call it something better than "i" like "fileCounter"

```
        if (PackagingPhoto1.HasFile && PackagingPhoto1.PostedFiles.Count <= 3)
        {
            int fileCounter = 0;
            foreach (HttpPostedFile file in PackagingPhoto1.PostedFiles) 
            {
```

Step 2:
Get rid of the for loop and just increment fileCounter once at that spot.

```
                        else
                        {
                            fileCounter++;
                            string Path = Server.MapPath("~/IncomingPhotos/" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "." + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + 
                            ".ReceivingPhoto" + fileCounter + extension);
                                file.SaveAs(Path);
                            Label9.Text = "Photos were successfully uploaded.";
                            Label9.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        }
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I needed. I had pretty much determined the for loop was the issue but tried all kinds of variations and couldn't figure out how to get the incrementing to work. Thanks again! Would you also be able to tell me if it's possible to create a folder at the same time that these photos are saved? So the path would be ---
`Server.MapPath("~/IncomingPhotos/" +
//create new folder with Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text as the name of that folder + //create another new folder with Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells[1]. as the name of that folder + "IncomingPhoto" + fileCounter + extension`

Comment: Look at Directory.CreateDirectory(string)  If you need more help, let me know